# How to select specific fields to update in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to get all records from a database with @where, then update them. To do this, I have created a query like this:

```
public async Task MarkAllAsActive()
{
    var currentUserId = _userManager.GetCurrentUserId();
    await _workOrders.Where(row => row.Status == WorkOrderStatus.Draft).ForEachAsync(row =>
    {
        row.Status = WorkOrderStatus.Active;
        _uow.MarkAsChanged(row, currentUserId);
    });
}
```

But this query selects all fields from the database which isn't good. To solve this I try to select just specific fields like `ID`, `Status`:

```
public async Task MarkAllAsActive()
{
    var currentUserId = _userManager.GetCurrentUserId();
    await _workOrders.Select(row=>new WorkOrder { Id=row.Id,Status=row.Status}).Where(row => row.Status == WorkOrderStatus.Draft).ForEachAsync(row =>
    {
        row.Status = WorkOrderStatus.Active;
        _uow.MarkAsChanged(row, currentUserId);
    });

}
```

But it return this error:

> The entity or complex type 'DataLayer.Context.WorkOrder' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

I've seen a similar post and the same error, but my problem is different because I want to update.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `.Select(row=>new {Id =row.Id,Status=row.Status})`, linq to entities allow use an anonymous type projections. And in my opinion you should first use `Where` next select needed items using `Select`.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki there is a problem . status is a an enum , and now I cant set a enum to status , it says can not assigned to -- . because its an anynoumos type

Comment: Add `_uow.MarkAsChanged()` also. I think you trying do update incorrectly way.

Comment: Consider using Raw SQL this time and use a regular `UPDATE workorders SET Status = ? WHERE Status = ?;` query. It's a pity there is not any way to do this via Entity Framework but if you're concerned about performance is the best way to do it.

Comment: @jorgonor I think your idea is better . I used `_uow.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction, "update dbo.workorder Set [Status]={0} where Status In ({1},{2})", 3, 2, 1);`

Comment: I am new to `LINQ` so bear with my idea. `var query (from a in (table) where (condition) select a ).ToList()` then user `ForEach` to update the fields you want and save. ?.

Comment: @KiRa I don't want to select all fields , your query `... select a` select all rows with all fields and its teribble

Comment: @workquestion sorry about my idea.. That's my way on how to update a field in a table. query it first to `ToList` and use `ForEach > query again by SingleOrDefault` and save.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you have to fetch the entire entity.
In order to update an entity with EF, the class type edited has to be a DbContext mapped entity .

If you want to Update **without fetching Entities** to the server , and **without writing any SQL** you can use [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) .

See the **update** section on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching entity within same entity will not work in your case, as you are getting only selected columns. e.g. You are fetching WorkOrder entity in WorkOrder again.
I would suggest you to use DTO to load selected columns only. It should work. But at the time of update you will have to copy same to db object.